# Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects. using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session

This is my index page

```
  session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["manager"])){

    header("location:admin_login.php");
    exit();
}
#Be sure to chack that this manager SESSION value is in fact in the database
$managerID =preg_replace('#[0.9]#l','',$_SESSION['id']);//filter everything but numbers and letters 
$manager = preg_replace('#[A_Za_z0.9]#i','',$_SESSION["manager"]);//filter everything but numbers and letters
$password = preg_replace('#[A_Za_z0.9]#i','',$_SESSION["password"]);//filter everything but numbers and letters
//Run mySQL query to be sure that this person is an admin and that thier password session var equals the database informartion
//Connect to MYSQL database
include "../storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `admin` WHERE id='$managerID' AND username='$manager' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1");//query the person
//........MAKE SURE PERSONE EXISTS IN DATABASE....
$existCount = mysql_num_rows($sql);//Count the row nums
if($existCount == 0){//evaluate the count
    header("location:../index.php");
    exit();
}
```

This is my admin_login page

```
   session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["manager"])){

    header("location:index.php");
    exit();
}

?>
<?php
#Palse the log in from if user has filled it out and pressed "Log In"
if(isset($_POST["username"])&&isset($_POST["password"])){

    $manager = preg_replace('#[A_Za_z0.9]#i','',$_POST["username"]);//filter everything but numbers and letters
    $password = preg_replace('#[A_Za_z0.9]#i','',$_POST["password"]);//filter everything but numbers and letters
    //connect to the MYSQL database
    include "../storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM `admin` WHERE username='$manager' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1");//query the person
    //........MAKE SURE THE PERSONE EXISTS IN DATABASE....
    $existCount = mysql_num_rows($sql);//Count the row nums 
    if($existCount==1){//evaluate the count
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
            $id=$row['id'];
        }
        $_SESSION["id"]=$id;
        $_SESSION["manager"]=$manager;
        $_SESSION["password"]=$password;
        header("location:index.php");
        exit(); 
    } else {
        echo "That information is incorrect,try again<a href='index.php'>Click Here</a>";
        exit(); 
    }
}
```

i have error on google chrome :

Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.

Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects.

Comment: From what I can see, you're constantly being redirected from `index.php` to `admin_login.php` and vice-versa if `$_SESSION["manager"]` isn't set.

Answer (score 1):

In both index page and admin_login page, there is  $_SESSION["manager"] check and hence if the manager index is not set, there is a redirection loop between these two URLs.

You may want to remove the Session check in admin_login page.

Answer (score 0):

try to `var_dump($_SESSION);`, it's either not set properly or session is not started